# Filtering data by category for statistical test in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am working with a dataframe to carry out a test in Python.

```
Group    Count 
B        21 
B        13 
A        25 
A        75 
A        11 
B        15
```

As long as it is just for one section or category as such, the test is fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats

valuespergroup = [col for col_name, col in df.groupby('Group')['Count']]
stats.ranksums(*valuespergroup)
```

Now, consider the following:

```
Category Group  Count
S1  P   21
S1  P   13
S1  A   25
S1  A   75
S1  A   10
S1  P   10
S2  P   21
S2  P   14
S2  A   29
S2  A   95
S2  A   15
S2  P   18
```

I need to process by category, meaning passing the data for S1 first, then S2, etc.. I tried putting category in the groupby, but it does not work. The function takes two arguments only.

**Updates:**
I tried the following codes, but it will print the entire data for each category
and I don't think it is passed correctly to the test either. It's along the lines I want to do. The final output should be:
S1  test results 
S2  test results

```
groupby_Category = df.groupby('Category')

for  Category in groupby_Category:
     values_per_group = [col for col_name, col in df3.groupby(['Group'])['Count']]

     print(Category, stats.ranksums(*values_per_group))
```

Comment: I tried to extend this to a case with another variable like category.. Say category2 without success. The only way my check works is if manually subset the dataframe by each value of the category and then apply the function to the reduced data.Let say Category takes values (a,b,c)
Ex. Cutback = df[df['category2']=='a']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working attempt should work. However, you are using an unknown *df3*. Simply replace this with actual dataframe from iteration of your groupby object, *sub_df*. In fact, extend your loop to build a dataframe of results from a list of dictionaries.

```
groupby_Category = df.groupby('Category')

data_list = []

for i, sub_df in groupby_Category:
     values_per_group = [col for col_name, col in sub_df.groupby(['Group'])['Count']]

     res = stats.ranksums(*values_per_group)
     print(i, res)
     # S1 RanksumsResult(statistic=0.8728715609439696, pvalue=0.38273308888522595)
     # S2 RanksumsResult(statistic=1.091089451179962, pvalue=0.27523352407483426)

     data_list.append({'Category': i, 'statistic': res[0], 'p_value': res[1]})

ranksums_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
print(ranksums_df)
#   Category   p_value  statistic
# 0       S1  0.382733   0.872872
# 1       S2  0.275234   1.091089
```

Comment: This is awesome. I now see clearly what I was missing.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Happy coding!

Comment: I  tried to extend this using a second category variable, category2(A,B,C). I tried various approaches including using a nested for loop to get it to subset the data by A first, pass it to the function, then by B, and C to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean to do. If subset by both variables, pass into groupby: `groupby_Category = df.groupby(['Category', 'Category2'])`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need `groupby` `'Group','Category'`

```
for x , y in df.groupby(['Group','Category'])['Count']:
    print(x,y)



('A', 'S1') 2    25
3    75
4    10
Name: Count, dtype: int64
('A', 'S2') 8     29
9     95
10    15
Name: Count, dtype: int64
('P', 'S1') 0    21
1    13
5    10
Name: Count, dtype: int64
('P', 'S2') 6     21
7     14
11    18
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am not interested in printing each category and its data element, but rather passing the entire category to be processed by the test and return the result.  I tried this.  It's not quite right but is along the way of what I want to do: 
groupby_Category = df.groupby('Category') 
for  Category in groupby_Category: 
    values_per_group = [col for col_name, col in df3.groupby(['Group'])['Count']] 
    print(Category, stats.ranksums(*values_per_group))